# Safe wiring on linkable shop light?

Tags: led, safety, wiring

Question about  Smart Electrician® 3650 Lumens 46" LED Linkable Shop Light Model Number: 0053-0011 | Menards® SKU: 3481400

I bought several of these and am having the same glowing issue referenced in the link below. I wanted to not spend a lot of money and just need them for short term, maybe 2-3 years at most so wasn't worried about high, long term quality. However, I also don't want to burn the place down! Are these safe to use as is? Would it be worthwhile to rewire them? Thank you!

Please reference [LED light fixture glows when not turned on](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/317915/led-light-fixture-glows-when-not-turned-on/389297#389297)

Comment: It can be done but seems hardly worth it for these Cheese cheapies - 4' shop lights are so common/cheap.  If you enjoy kitbashing lights, *real, actual fluorescent* is the place to be.  There's nothing cooler than taking a 1954 fluorescent fixture off Craigslist that's tough like it's out of a Navy ship, little sanding, some rattle-can white, slap a T8 programmed start ballast and 90CRI tubes, and suddenly it's *magnificent*...

Comment: What kind of switch is it?

Comment: Harper, I hear you and agree, but as I said, I was looking for something fast, easy and cheap for a few years run. My question and concern with these, the way they are wired, is if they are safe to use as is. Thank you!

Comment: Tyson, it's a pull chain, but the white wire is connected to the switch.

Comment: @Scassmeyer Please [register](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) your account and then [merge](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting multiple responses as answers can result in an automated lock that can prevent others from assisting you.